# Prepended SCSS mixins with CSS variables not working in NextJS

Tags: css, sass, next.js

I've got the following next.config.js setup

```
module.exports = (phase, {defaultConfig}) => {
  if ('sassOptions' in defaultConfig) {
      defaultConfig['sassOptions'] = {
          includePaths: ['./styles'],
          prependData: `@import "styles/mixins.scss";`,
      }
  }
  return defaultConfig;
}
```

and while the following mixin works flawlessly within my xyz.module.scss

```
@mixin panelBoxShadow() {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 7px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.11);
}

// Used in module.scss like
@include buttonBoxShadow();
```

this mixin doesn't work at all

```
@mixin maxWidth($value) {
  @media (max-width: $value) {
    @content
  }
}

// Used in module.scss like
@include maxWidth(var(--tablet)) {
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
    ... 
}
```

I know that SCSS/SASS is a preprocessor and its evaluated before the var() CSS variables, however how can I make this work without having to go back to manually importing the mixins.scss in every xyz.module.scss and using SCSS variables in there? Is there even a way?

Comment: I don't think you're able to use css variables in media queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this :

```
@mixin maxWidth($value) {
  prop: var(#{$value});
}

@include maxWidth(--tablet);
```

Because SCSS pre-compiles the CSS, you'll have the literal `$value` in your browser.
So, instead of passing `var(--tablet)`, just pass `--tablet`.
`#{value}` will tell SCSS to write the literal value of the variable, so it will write `--tablet` instead of trying to find its value. Then now you can wrap it in the `var()`. And your browser will do the stuff.